# Invariance of Space and Time in Different Reference Frames

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm studying dynamics by Anil Rao's book. He said something that made me really confused. The citations below construct the problem.

> [...]
>
> An assumption of Newtonian mechanics is that space is invariant with
> respect to changes in reference frames, i.e., observations made of
> space are the same in all reference frames. As a result of the
> assumption of the invariance of space, observations of an arbitrary
> vector **b** are the same regardless of the reference frame. Consequently,
> for any two reference frames A and B we have
>
> $ {}^{A} {\bf b} = {}^{B} {\bf b} = {\bf b}$
>
> [...]

Then he talks about rate of change of a vector function:

> [...] given an arbitrary vector function of time, at every instant of time
> observers in all reference frames see the same vector. In other words,
> a vector is independent of the reference frame in which it is
> observed. However, unlike a scalar function of time, observers in
> different reference frames do not see the same rate of change of a
> vector function of time. Contrariwise, observers fixed in different
> reference frames will, in general, make different observations about
> the rate of change of a vector function of time. As a result, the
> phrase “rate of change of a vector” must always be qualified by
> stating explicitly the reference frame in which the observation is
> being made.
>
> [...]

Further, about velocity:

> It is important to understand that the notation $ {}^{A} {\bf v} $ is
> merely a shorthand for $ {}^{A} d{\bf r}/dt $. In other words, when we
> write $ {}^{A} {\bf v} $, we mean that the vector $ {}^{A} {\bf v} $
> arises from taking the rate of change of another vector (in this case
> position) in reference frame A. Furthermore, it is important to
> understand that, although $ {}^{A} {\bf v} $ arises from taking the
> rate of change of r in reference frame A, the quantity $ {}^{A} {\bf v} $
> is itself a vector. Consequently, by assumption observations of
> the vector $ {}^{A} {\bf v} $ are the same in all reference frames.

1. The rate of change of the position is dependent of the frame of reference.
2. Velocity is the rate of change of the position.

So why velocity is independent of reference frame?

Or more generally: i can't understand why vectors are independent of reference frame, but their rate of change are.

Comment: We have $\mathbf v (t) = \frac{d\mathbf x}{dt}$. Taking $\mathbf x (t) \rightarrow \mathbf x(t) + \mathbf C$ does nothing to $\mathbf v$.

Comment: @HantingZhang but if $ c = c(t) $ ? We could have a frame of reference where $ c $ varies with time (e.g., a frame moving with constant velocity).

Comment: I think you've been asking the wrong question. All "vectors" are independent of their reference frame. If $\frac{d\mathbf a}{dt} = \mathbf b$, since $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are both vectors, they're both frame independent. So both vectors and their rate of change are independent of the reference frame.

Comment: Also, Anil Rao is contradicting himself, if what you write is true, because he states that: "rate of change of a vector” must always be qualified by stating explicitly the reference frame in which the observation is being made. But then he says that: "Consequently, by assumption observations of the vector $^A\mathbf v$ are the same in all reference frames." I can't think of what the "rate of change of a vector” would be other than a vector.